# C# Pinger not working properly

Tags: c#, ping

My code does ping successfully  but now working.

```
public static bool IsHostnameAlive(string address)
{
    bool Alive = false;
    try
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(address);

        Alive = (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
        MessageBox.Show(address + " is online.");
    }
    catch
    {
        Alive = false;
        MessageBox.Show(address + " is offline or does not allow ICMP traffic.");
    }
    return Alive;
}
```

Lets say that the address is http://www.example.com/

I would ping that and it would say that it was offline.

If I was to change that address to example.com

It would say that it was online.

However, if I were to ping an address that didn't exist, e.g: idfnwjfneriugelhfnaiorfge.com

It would say that was online as well when it's not.

Does anybody know why it does this?

Comment: **Read the exception message**.  You aren't getting the error you think you are.  And you probably have a DNS server that returns fake hosts.

Answer (score 3):

You do **say** it's online even if the ping failed:

```
MessageBox.Show(address + " is online.");
```

I'd guess you want to change that to:

```
if (Alive) {
    MessageBox.Show(address + " is online.");
else {
    MessageBox.Show(address + " is offline or does not allow ICMP traffic.");
}
```

When you try to ping an invalid address (something that isn't an IP or a valid DNS name) the `catch` handles it. But if you try to ping a valid IP or DNS name (e.g. 192.168.200.237) that doesn't respond, you set `Alive` to `false`, but then you show a messagebox saying that **192.168.200.237 is online.**.